# d3js - collection of downloadable examples?

Tags: d3.js

As I am offline for a while I am looking for a collection of downloadable examples for the d3js library. Is there a way to download the examples from [d3js gallery](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery) and/or examples from 
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock without making trouble for the websites? Or has somebody a collection of examples from these sources as a bundled download?

Thanks buddies

martin

Comment: Your favorite website crawler (e.g. [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/)) should do, maybe with a sleep period between downloads.

Comment: Thanks Lars, crawling seems always the last opportunity to choose yet i assume ...

Answer (score 1):

d3 used to come bundled with a bunch of examples, you can find old releases [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/releases?after=v2.8.0).  You can also download the gist manually a bit of a pita though.  You can also download tutorials like [Tips and Tricks](http://www.d3noob.org/) by Noob (and others as well).